# How to uninstall .exe file from windows control panel fro puppet manifest

Tags: puppet

I want to uninstall the .exe file from control panel
I already installed WinRAR file but when I tried uninstall the program from puppet manifest but it is not working.
I want to completely uninstall the program, what code I should write in manifest?
Please help me...

```
 package {  
    WinRAR":  
    ensure => absent,  
    source => "C:\\Softwares\WinRAR.exe",  
    require => File["C:\\Softwares\WinRAR.exe"],  
    subscribe => File["C:\\Program Files\WinRAR"],  
    uninstall_options => ['/S'],  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Name the package exactly as it's called in Control Panel -> Add/Remove Software.

Comment: Please send me another solution

Comment: Please help me for solution